# Bash Script download file from url

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to download csv file from link which i need to first login to site. But it does not download anything. When i enter the link to chrome it immediately starts to download csv file. Link is basically belongs to clickable button in website. Login page of website is different btw. It's http://192.28.101.51:16001/login

```
wget --user=username --ask-password http://192.28.101.51:16001/getProductNameWithID
```

Comment: Probably you have a HTML login page, and not the HTTP authentification (so at different level). In that case, read the page, accept the cookies, store them, and in the second request you put in the FORM the login data. [ev. you should copy also the hidden cookies in POST]. You just have to simulate what you and your browser do: download the loigin page, push the authentification data, and get back the result

Comment: i'm sorry but this is the first time i'm writing shell script so i don't know how to do steps that you explained.

Comment: I hope somebody will find the duplicate question. It requires some time to write the answer (and explain it) (because it may involve additional steps, and some customization).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that the site stores cookie in Chrome so no password is prompted. In this case you may need a terminal-based browser. Here I use `w3m`.

First log in first manually:

```
w3m -cookie http://192.28.101.51:16001/login
```

Log in and then press `Q` to quit.

Then you can try downloading the file as:

```
w3m -cookie http://192.28.101.51:16001/getProductNameWithID > output_file
```

Comment: this is going to be shell script and  you can enter without password but username is needed.